# LimeSurvey additional attributes not working (CSV upload)

Tags: importerror, survey, limesurvey, import-csv

I am trying to upload a list of survey participants on LimeSurvey (Ver 2.06) with a .CSV file.

I have the following columns: firstname lastname email attribute_1 attribute_2 attribute_3

When I try uploading the CSV file, only firstname, lastname, and email show up on the token list. The three additional attributes do not show up at all. FYI they are country names, company names, and titles - nothing long.

Please help! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to also create the additional attributes at the Limesurvey admin backend. If the additional token attributes were not created before upload, uploading the data will fail.